# Shorten the generated ID from new Date().getTime()

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to shorten the generated ID number.

```
Output 1: 917114801680
Output 2: 417114800753
Output x: 817114802119
```

Notice that `1711480` is the same in all the generated ID. I would like to remove `1711`  and shorten the generated ID to say 8 digits from the current 12 digits.

```js
function test() {
  var min = 1;
  var max = 9;
  var num = Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
//  var timeNow = new Date().getTime();
    var timeNow = Math.floor(new Date().getTime() / 100);
  document.getElementById('field10').value = num + '' + timeNow;
}
window.onload = test;
setTimeout(function () {
  console.log(document.getElementById('field10').value);
}, 500);
```

```html
<input type="text" id="field10" />
```

Comment: It's not an "id", it's a count of the number of milliseconds since a recognized "epoch" date. Stripping out some digits kind-of doesn't make a lot of sense.

Comment: PSA: It's 2024 and time to learn about `let` and `const` in preference to `var`.

Comment: Why the time element and not a fully random ID?

Comment: Yes, it's not an ID but I'm using it to generate a unique ID. Sorry for the confusion but yes, I don't need the `1711` and want it removed. Please help.

Comment: Also you're prefixing the timestamp value (divided by 100? why?) with a random number *as a string*, so the resulting "id" is weird. What is it that you are actually trying to do, and what are the constraints that lead you to believe shortening the values is a good (necessary?) idea?

Comment: *"I would like to remove 1711"* - Are you just looking for the `%` operator?  For example: `Math.floor(new Date().getTime() / 100) % 17110000000`  (Which of course would have to change every so often, since it's a timestamp.)

Comment: @tadman That's because there's a chance of a random ID being the same when 1000s are generated.

Comment: @David Works great. Please post as an answer.

Comment: A) How many IDs are you going to generate? B) What is your tolerance for collisions? C) How long an identifier can you handle? If you're generating 10+ digit numbers then you're unlikely to ever have a collision unless you're making in excess of 10^7 IDs, as per the [Birthday Paradox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birthday_problem) calculation.

Comment: I think you should consider the parameters of your unique ID problem more systematically. How many ID values are to be generated? How often? What are the consequences of collisions? What are the constraints on the size of the ID values, and how important and flexible are they? If the constraints are inflexible, what are the best possible outcomes from generating random ID values? etc etc

Comment: If you strip off 1711 from those values, you'll hit a duplicate ID value on April 7th.

Comment: @ElaineByene: I'm hesitant to post arithmetic as an answer.  If that's truly all you needed then the best thing is likely to just delete the question entirely.  For the underlying purpose of the value being generated, there are other considerations to be made here.  Just removing numbers from a value is unlikely to be of any use to future readers.

Comment: `Date.now()` is more concise than `new Date().getTime()` and returns the same value...

Comment: Why not just use a better way to generate UIDs? See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/105034/how-do-i-create-a-guid-uuid for many ways.

Comment: @ElaineByene generally you don't create unique ids in the _browser_. Can you say more about the use case that you need a unique ID for? There are _levels_ of "unique" and it's going to be hard to truly help you without understanding what level of uniqueness you need.